What are the names of all four wifes of four sons of King Dashratha?
What are the names of all four wifes of four sons of King Dashratha ??

As per Valmiki Ramayan, King Janak have 2 daughters namely Sita and Urmila who became the wives of Lord Ram and his brother Lakshman. Mandavi and Shrutkirit who became the wives of Bharat and Shatrughan respectively were the daughters of Kushdhwaj who was the brother of King Janak.
